# Rails 7 | GET Request not working in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get, payment-gateway, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a rails 7 app where when the user clicks the button, it redirects to a payment gateway for doing payments online via GET Request, in my development mode, in local machine (on localhost:3000), it works perfectly fine.

> orders_controller.rb

```
def paye
        @payment_response = Easebuzz::Payment.initiate({
          "txnid" => "#{@order.id}",
          "amount" => amount.to_f,
          "firstname" => current_user.name,
          "email" => current_user.email,
          "phone" => current_user.phone_number,
          "productinfo" => "Payment for Order#{@order.id}",
          "surl" => "http://localhost:3000/orders/#{@order.id}/successE",
          "furl" => "http://localhost:3000/orders/#{@order.id}/failedTransaction",
        })

        if @payment_response['status'] == 1
          data = @payment_response['data']
          redirect_to("https://testpay.easebuzz.in/pay/#{data}", allow_other_host: true, status: 303)
        end

       puts @payment_response
end
```

> routes.rb:

```
resources :orders do
  member do
      get '/paye', to: 'orders#paye'
  end
 end
```

> index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to paye_order_path(order) %>
```

so as i said, in develpment mode, it is working absolutely fine, but when i use it in production which i deployed using aws ec2, apache and passenger, and just changed

```
def paye
     .....
          "surl" => "http://(Main Domain.in)/orders/#{@order.id}/successE",
          "furl" => "http://(Main Domain.in)/orders/#{@order.id}/failedTransaction",
     ......

     .......
          redirect_to("https://pay.easebuzz.in/pay/#{data}", allow_other_host: true, status: 303) 
          #using pay.easebuzz in production
       .....
  puts @payment_response
end
```

Only 1st time it worked in production, then from 2nd time, it wasn't working.

the GET request is showing `(OrdersController#payE is missing a template for request formats: text/html)`

but in development, it is working absolutely fine, why is it not doing GET request in production??

also `puts @payment_response` is not showing anything in the logs.

So my main problem is that The GET request (payE method in order_controller.rb) is working in development, but when using in production, it is not working, it is not reading the Easebuzz::Payment.initiate

also i changed from payE from GET to POST request to see if it will `puts @payment_response`, but it is showing `No template found for OrdersController#payE` in logs.

What dumb thing am i doing here?

Comment: The issue is likely that there is an error with Easebuzz::Payment.initiate. Add a payE.html.erb template to your views, which you likely need if there is a failure anyway.  You can use that to help debug.

Comment: Note, `"#{x}"` and `x` are effectively the same if `x` is a String. If you want to convert it to one, `x.to_s` is the typical method. The quoted style is a `bash` thing.

Answer (score 1):

So the fact that it's erroring on a template issue means that `@payment_response['status'] == 1` is not true. `puts @payment_response` is probably not working because STDOUT is not tied to your logs in production, you could try `Rails.logger.debug @payment_response.inspect`.

So that should help you see the response, and my best guess would be that your `Easebuzz` config is not setup properly to use the right merchant key or something for production, but you'll know more once you see the logs.

Finally, your code *should* handle an error more gracefully, ie. you should have an `else` for that check, with either a local redirect with a flash error, or maybe a template with an error displayed to the user.

Comment: thanks!
i found what dumb thing i was doing, I needed to have new transaction id each time (even if we refresh the page, it should have a unqiue txnid), but there i was using @order.id which is also unique ONCE but when i used the same id again, it wasnt working, i was being totally dumb without reading docs :'  ).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i was being totally Dumb without reading the docs on Easebuzz, during Live Payments, i needed to use Unique Transaction ID :')

notice i used `"txnid"`, it refers to the transaction id, So each time when a transaction occurs (i.e when the user clicks the button and payment page pops up), that payment page is nothing but a transaction, or we can say it is built with the unique transaction id, it should be having a unique id, i was using the id which is a built-in unique id which comes with SQL (whenever we create a model or something in rails).

(here i used `@order.id`) and everytime i was doing `rails db:setup` to start fresh and the database would reset (notice that i have already used that unique id the first time i used the Live Payment on production,so it worked only 1 time, then later it wasn't working).

So next time when i was starting fresh using `rails db:setup` i was creating the order with the same id (which would be 1 at the start obviously which i have already used once for the first time).

So i fixed it bu using

orders_controller.rb

```
def payE
        unique_txnid = "#{Time.now.to_i}_#{rand(100000..999999)}"
        @payment_response = Easebuzz::Payment.initiate({
          "txnid" => unique_txnid,
          "amount" => amount.to_f,
          "firstname" => current_user.name,
          "email" => current_user.email,
          "phone" => current_user.phone_number,
          "productinfo" => "Payment for Order#{@order.id}",
          "surl" => "http://localhost:3000/orders/#{@order.id}/successE",
          "furl" => "http://localhost:3000/orders/#{@order.id}/failedTransaction",
        })

        if @payment_response['status'] == 1
          data = @payment_response['data']
          redirect_to("https://pay.easebuzz.in/pay/#{data}", allow_other_host: true, status: 303)
        end

end
```